# My Spring Boot App fails resolving a bean, but only, in windows and tomcat deployment

Tags: spring, spring-boot

First of all, thank you so much for your help.

I have a big pile of mud-legacy application, with lots of injections through fields (not constructors), and many many classes.

I am facing a weird bug, but only rises if the deployment is done as a war in tomcat-windows. If I start the app with java -jar mywar.war, everthing runs fine, but If deploy it in tomcat, on windows, it fails with the following error:

> No qualifying bean of type XYZ

As I said before, everything runs ok if I started the app via java -jar in both, linux or windows.

### UPDATES ON 2021/01/05

Hi again! I'been debugging spring source code since yesterday and I have found some differences:

- On linux & windows, standalone mode, the spring classes AbstractBeanFactory and singletons initialization stuff is called for the bean XYZ (creating a proxy object),
- On the other hand, on tomcat & windows, those classes and methods are not called for the bean XYZ, so there's no proxy object.

Also

I've found that, running in standalone mode, the bean that sometimes rises the "no qualifying bean", is in a certain position at the config classes list, but in tomcat, it is in a very later position:

```java
   this.reader.loadBeanDefinitions(configClasses);
```

I'm still don't know the difference of that order

### MORE UPDATES

The order of the dependencies scanned by spring differs in embedded tomcat and external tomcat.

The first, uses org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader

External tomcat, uses org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader

That produces a different order for the scanned (and initialization) of beans

Anybody has any clues about this different behaviour?

Regards

Comment: Same java and tomcat versions? Same configuration of tomcat?

Comment: Same major version. I mean: java8 and tomcat 8. Probably not same patch versions (8.5.X and 8.5.Y) and java 1.8.0_XYZ and 1.8.0_ABC

Maybe something with a "path ordering issue" on windows_????

Comment: I would strongly suggest at least using the same tomcat version as that might make a difference.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum ! Thanks again! I'm gonna try to install a local tomcat with same version as the conflicting windows one and check the results. I hope to get it done in an hour

Comment: Nothing. I've tried with same versions in linux, windows and even, upgrading to latest tomcat version in windows. Same result: in linux and in windows-standalone-jar, spring boot starts without errors, but deployed on tomcat, rises the No qualiying bean of type error... :\

Comment: So I've come across this before, if you are using the embedded Tomcat that is built into spring and run your app via the command line like `java -jar mywar.war` it is fine because it uses the embedded tomcat instance only, however when we ran the same war file in a separate tomcat instance it blow up. My understanding is that it's trying to load the embedded tomcat instance as well as the tomcat instance you've put the app in so it goes all we're at the JVM level.

Comment: So, it's possible that the embdded tomcat jars are being included in the war? I'm gonna check it right now!

Thanks a lot! @Popeye

Comment: I'm afraid this is not the cause of the problem. I've removed tomcat-related-jars from the war and the problem still remains...

I will continue debugging. Thanks a lot again for your response!

Answer (score 0):

I've found something that matches our current problems. It is described here.

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57129

Looks like, from tomcat 7 to 8, tomcat class path resolver changed the way it works (processing libs in alphabetic order).

So, I'm trying this patch and hope it works.

https://github.com/openwide-java/tomcat-classloader-ordered